# Difficulty with Scraping Table (Python,BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am struggling with scraping the table from this website:

http://www.espn.com/mlb/lines

Specifically, I am trying to scrape the column "Run Line" for the row "Westgate" for every game listed in the table.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong as I am just trying to get down to the text within the table, which from my limited understanding of webscraping would be the second table within the "oddrow" table I have selected.

I have tried searching my issue, but I have had trouble applying any proposed solutions to my specific scenario.

Thank you for any help in advance.

Here is my code so far

```
url='http://www.espn.com/mlb/lines'
driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
content=driver.page_source

soup=BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml')

driver.quit()

table=soup.find('table',{'class':'tablehead'})
table_row=table.find_all('tr',{'class':'oddrow'})
table_data=table_row.find_all('table',{'class':'tablehead'})[1] #trying to 
#just scrape the second table only within this row, ie the Westgate and Runline table

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-397-fea09cb40cb2> in <module>()
----> 1 table_data=table_row.find_all('table',{'class':'tablehead'})

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py in __getattr__(self, key)
   1805     def __getattr__(self, key):
   1806         raise AttributeError(
-> 1807             "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
   1808         )

AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following gives your desired output, there may be a better way to do this but i used a nested loop to increment i until it is 3 since you want the 3rd table in the soup each time, then I increment the oddrowindex this returns the Run Line column from westgate row within a loop:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url='http://www.espn.com/mlb/lines'
driver = webdriver.webdriver.Chrome() 
driver.get(url)
content=driver.page_source

oddrowindex = 0
soup=BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml')

while oddrowindex < 70:
        i = 0
        table_row=soup.find_all('tr',{'class':'oddrow'})[oddrowindex]
        for td in table_row:
                if (i == 3):
                        print(td.text)
                i = i + 1
                oddrowindex = oddrowindex + 1

driver.quit()
```

Sample output :

[image]

Comment: Hello, I am diving into your solution a little bit more and am having trouble understanding it.  Two questions for you... 

1). How are you able to skip over the oddrows we don't want, ie WilliamHill and CG Technology?

2). I only see two table classes in terms of the HTML under each oddrow, are the tables in this case, the 'text-align:center'? Furthermore, how does the i variable know you are referring to these tables exactly?

Comment: The i variable is getting incremented for each of the td inside of the tr class oddrow, each td it reads it increments and then on the 3rd (Run Line) it will print those contents